# What to do in such a situation xamarin?

Tags: c#, api, xaml, design-patterns, xamarin

I've two ways to get the data. An Api and in local storage (Sqlite) cache.
I used the Repository pattern and made two repository returns a collection of entities. But to whom to entrust the proxy requests to repositories. If there is evidence that taking from Sqlite otherwise make a request to the API.

Comment: Are you asking how to decide whether to use your local cache or make a request to the remote API? Doesn't that depend on your needs? If it's cached (and still valid), take it from the cache, otherwise ask the API and cache that result.

Comment: I mean how to implement the api proxy to cache class

Comment: Well, the [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) comes to mind. Implement the API once with calls to the actual API and decorate that with the caching class.